# Programmatically get Account Id from lambda context arn

Tags: aws-lambda

I have access to

```
com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
```

object and by extension the invoked function Arn. The arn contains the account Id where the lambda resides.

My question is simple, I want the cleanest way to extract the account Id from that.

I was taking a look

com.amazon.arn.ARN;

It has a whole bunch of stuff, but no account ID (which i presume is due to the fact that not all arns have account ids ?)

I want to cleanly extract the account Id, without resorting to parsing the string.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your lambda is being used as an API Gateway proxy lambda, then you have access to `event.requestContext.accountId` (where `event` is the first parameter to your handler function).

Otherwise, you will have to split the ARN up.

From the [AWS documentation about ARN formats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-lambda), here are the valid Lambda ARN formats:

> arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name
>
> arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name:alias-name
>
> arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name:version
>
> arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:event-source-mappings:event-source-mapping-id

In all cases, `account-id` is the 5th item in the ARN (treating `:` as a separator). Therefore, you can just do this:

```
String accountId = arn.split(":")[4];
```

Comment: Sigh, that is what i was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Yes, it's a little nasty. At least the various ARN formats are easily accessible on the docs site.

Answer (score 11):

You no longer need to parse the arn anymore, sts library has introduced `get_caller_identity` for this purpose.
Its an overkill, but works!.

Excerpts from aws docs.

`python`

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sts')
response = client.get_caller_identity()['Account']
```

`js`

```
/* This example shows a request and response made with the credentials for a user named Alice in the AWS account 123456789012. */

 var params = {
 };
 sts.getCallerIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    Account: "123456789012", 
    Arn: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice", 
    UserId: "AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE"
   }
   */
 });
```

More details [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity) & [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#getCallerIdentity-property)

Comment: For Python3, in my Lambda function, this worked:  
`account = client.get_caller_identity().get('Account')`

Comment: there is an erroneous extra brace at the end of your python example:

`response = client.get_caller_identity()['Account'])`

should be

`response = client.get_caller_identity()['Account']`

Comment: Corrected! Thanks.

Comment: you need to have the `sts:GetCallerIdentity` IAM permission for this to work

Comment: Note that this gets the caller's account id. This  might be different than the account id of the account that is hosting the lambda. If you gave given permission to another account to call your lambda, you will get the caller's account id, not your account id

Comment: in fact I've switched from accessing account id dynamically to setting it as an env variable using the cloudformation's `AWS::AccountId`. This is okay for me since I'm not using a cross account access or any other complex logic that requires distinguishing  account hosting the lambda Vs. account invoking the lambda.

Answer (score 5):

I would get the Account id from the context parameter in the following way.

```
ACCOUNT_ID = context.invoked_function_arn.split(":")[4]
```

aws doc referring context parameter -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
ACCID:  { "Fn::Join" : ["", [{ "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, "" ]] }
```

Comment: yea i know how to ref it in CFN. I wanted a lambda only method (so as to be agnostic to how the lambda was created).

Comment: This gives a dummy account id when doing a SAM local invoke using a AWS profile so ends up being problematic for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

### golang

```golang
import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambdacontext"
)

func Handler(ctx context.Context) error {
    lc, ok := lambdacontext.FromContext(ctx)
    if !ok {
        return errors.Errorf("could not get lambda context")
    }
    AwsAccountId := strings.Split(lc.InvokedFunctionArn, ":")[4]
```